# Finding the smallest integer such that a given condition holds with "binary search"

Tags: performance-tuning, programming

**Setup.** Suppose we are given a function $$f:\mathbb N\to\{\text{False},\text{True}\}$$ such that $$f(n)=\text{True}\implies f(n+1)=\text{True}$$
and such that $f(n)=\text{True}$ for some $n$ large enough.

**In natural language.** The function $f$ imposes a condition on the natural numbers which is fulfilled once $n$ is large enough.

**My question 1.** How can I, for any given $f$, find the smallest $n$ such that $f(n)=\text{True}$?

A first idea would be to start with $n=1$ and to increment $n$ by one until $f(n)$ is True. However, this is fairly slow. The next step is a "binary search" algorithm (see below).

**My question 2.** How can I implement a good algorithm in Mathematica?

Here is an example of the first algorithm that I thought of, implemented in Python:

```
def bin_search(cond):
    n = 1
    while not cond(n):
        n *= 2
    lower_bound = n//2
    upper_bound = n
    middle = (lower_bound + upper_bound)//2
    while upper_bound - lower_bound > 1:
        if cond(middle):
            upper_bound = middle
        else:
            lower_bound = middle
        middle = (lower_bound + upper_bound)//2
    return upper_bound
```

---

For example, one such condition would be $$f(n)=[H_n\geq 10],$$

where $$H_n=\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1i$$ is the $n$th harmonic number.

EDIT: A remark about the harmonic numbers: In fact I wanted to compare the runtime of a good brute force method against an intelligent method for this problem. For solving $H_n\geq 10$, it suffices to find the smallest integer $n$ such that $$\ln(n)+\gamma\geq 10,$$ where $\gamma$ denotes the Euler-Mascheroni constant. So we can find $$n=[ \exp(10-\gamma)],$$ where $[\cdot]$ denotes the nearest integer function.

Comment: **1.** You are asking two different questions: (Q1) an algorithm derivation one, and (Q2) a code translation one. Which one do you want? **2.** If Q1, then there is no need for ugly Python code... :)

Comment: @AntonAntonov Since I am looking at general $f$, my question is: What is a good implementation in Mathematica of a good algorithm which is able to find the smallest $n$ such that ...? *I don't want to use any specific properties of $f$ except the two mentioned above..*. My Python code was just an example of the simplest algorithm I could come up with, namely, a sort of binary search in order to find the minimal $n$

Comment: @AntonAntonov By the way, what is wrong with the Python implementation? 

Comment: You are aware, of course, that the problem has no solution in general, right? One can always construct a sequence growing slower than the $2^n$ built in the algorithm.

Comment: @yarchik I don't quite understand? My implementation will "always halt" with the correct result after a finite time. And it is at least much faster than the algorithm which just checks for $n=1,2,3,\dots$

Comment: Imagine a number of the form $10^{10^{10^{^{10}}}}$. The run time will not be so small. $2^{n}$ progression is faster than $n$, but not as fast as needed.

Comment: @yarchik Maybe my original question wasn't clear: Suppose that the evaluation of $f$ at any integer $m$ takes only constant time (admittedly, this assumption doesn't hold for my example with the harmonic numbers). Let $n$ be the smallest integer such that $f(n)=\text{True}$. Then I want the runtime of my algorithm to be a slow-growing function of $n$, for example $O(\ln(n))$. I think (I haven't checked this) that my implementation indeed achieves such a runtime for an arbitrary "fast-computable" $f$

Comment: @yarchik Actually, based on your Input, I will consider asking a part of this question on the StackExchange for theoretical Computer Science. That might reduce the confusion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one implementation of your algorithm:

```
firstTrue[f_] := next[f, 1, Infinity]

next[f_, last_, cur_] := If[last + 1 == cur,
    If[f[last], last, cur],
    If[f[last], next[f, dec[last], last], next[f, inc[last], cur]]
]

inc[n_] := With[{e = IntegerExponent[n, 2]},
    If[n == 2^e, 2^(e+1), n + 2^(e-1)]
]

dec[n_] := With[{e = IntegerExponent[n, 2]},
    If[n == 2^e, 2^(e-1) + 2^(e-2), n - 2^(e-1)]
]
```

Your example:

```
firstTrue[HarmonicNumber[#] >= 10&]
```

> 12367

Of course, for analytic functions like [`HarmonicNumber`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HarmonicNumber) there are much better algorithms to do this.

Comment: Thank you! About HarmonicNumber: I will add some motivation; of course you are right

Comment: Ok I have added some motivation to the Harmonic Number problem. In my opinion it is a very nice solution using Euler-Mascheroni

Answer (score 2):

As 
[Carl Woll says](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/210675/34008):

> Of course, for analytic functions like HarmonicNumber there are much better algorithms to do this.

Here is some code related to that statement -- it uses one of the universal WL functions:

```
Clear[H];
H[n_] := Sum[1/i, {i, n}];

FindArgMin[{H[n], H[n] >= 10, n > 0}, n]
(* {12366.5} *)

N@H[Ceiling[%[[1]]]]
(* 10. *)

N@H[Floor[%%[[1]]]]
(* 9.99996 *)
```

Comment: This is interesting because it simply uses numerical methods. A caveat is the innacuracy: For example, `FindArgMin[{H[n], H[n] >= 30, n > 0}, n, WorkingPrecision -> 1000, 
 AccuracyGoal -> 1000, PrecisionGoal -> 1000]` returns $$6.000022445096458984375\cdot 10^{12}$$ and the correct result is $$6000022499693$$ But it is indeed a very quick way to get close to the correct solution